# Soundcloud API (PHP) returns "invalid grant"

Tags: php, api, upload, soundcloud

We are using the code below to try to upload tracks from our WordPress site to SoundCloud through PHP. MP3 tracks are already on our server before running this script.

```
function upload_soundcloud()
{

    //App credentials. Create one at http://soundcloud.com/you/apps
    define('API_URL', 'https://api.soundcloud.com');
    define('CLIENT_ID', '$client_id');
    define('CLIENT_SECRET', '$client_secret');

    //User credentials
    define('EMAIL', '$email');
    define('PASSWORD', '$password');

    //Path to MP3 file to upload
    define('FILE', ABSPATH . '/wp-content/uploads/path/to/file.mp3');

    class SoundcloudAPI {
        private $url;
        private $clientID;
        private $secret;
        private $accessToken;

        public function __construct($url, $clientID, $secret) {
            $this->url = $url;
            $this->clientID = $clientID;
            $this->secret = $secret;
        }

        public function auth($username, $password) {
            $url = $this->url . '/oauth2/token';
            $data = array(
                'client_id' => $this->clientID,
                'client_secret' => $this->secret,
                'grant_type' => 'password',
                'username' => $username,
                'password' => $password
            );

            $result = $this->request($url, $data, 'POST');
            $this->accessToken = $result->access_token;
            return $result;
        }

        public function upload($title, $path) {
            $url = $this->url . '/tracks';
            $data = array(
                'oauth_token' => $this->accessToken,
                'track[title]' => $title,
                'track[asset_data]' => new CurlFile(realpath($path), 'audio/mpeg'),
            );

            $result = $this->request($url, $data, 'POST');
            return $result;
        }

        private function request($url, $data, $method) {
            $curl = curl_init();
            if ($method === 'POST') {
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
            } else {
                $url .= '?' . http_build_query($data);
            }
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
            $result = json_decode(curl_exec($curl));
            curl_close($curl);

            return $result;
        }
    }

    $soundCloud = new SoundcloudAPI(API_URL, CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET);
    $resultAuth = $soundCloud->auth(EMAIL, PASSWORD);
    $resultUpload = $soundCloud->upload('Test', FILE);

    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($resultAuth);
    print_r($resultUpload);
    echo '</pre>';

}
```

This is what we are getting as a response:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [error] => invalid_grant
)
```

Does anyone know why this might be happening? (the strangest part is that it was actually working 2 days ago, but then just stopped working and I feel like I am going crazy).

Comment: why are you defining a class inside a function? define it outside and create an instance inside your function and use it.

Comment: when you want to login using oAuth and you have client_id and client_secret, the grant_type should be authorization_code and not the password, more info https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/reference

Comment: Thanks for the replies guys, it seems there was just something wrong with the SoundCloud API or an issue the specific token, because now (3 days later) the code is working just fine again...

Comment: We're getting this error as well after doing more than 10 of these requests in a short time. Seems to be rate-limiting.

Comment: @DMalan I can confirm the same thing. It works fine calling the upload API for 4-5 uploads maximum, then I start getting "invalid grant", and it only goes back to normal 24 hours later. So there seems to be some kind of 24-hour limit when uploading tracks via the API. This makes it kind of useless for many situations. Can anyone else corroborate this?

Answer (score 0):

Try and save the access token and refresh token between requests (for example, in a local file or database) and reusing it. The rate-limit only seems to be on the `/oauth2/token` endpoint when using a username and password.

Once your access token has expired, you can use the refresh token to get a new one by making a request to `/oauth2/token` with:

```
'grant_type': 'refresh_token',
'client_id': <your client id>,
'client_secret': <your client secret>,
'refresh_token': <previous refresh token>
```

Comment: I can't believe I didn't know this, thanks so much, I will be trying it today!

Comment: It seems like it worked - now I have actually made it even easier for us by requesting a non-expiring token and saving it to/retrieving it from the database, and just re-using that token; Thanks for your help!

Comment: Nice. How did you request a non-expiring token?

Comment: It looks like this: 
'client_id' => 'CLIENTID',
client_secret' => 'CLIENTSECRET',
'grant_type' => 'password',
'username' => 'USERNAME', 
'password' => 'PASSWORD, 
'scope' => 'non-expiring'